# How to rearrange columns in a data set, so that one specific column appears before another?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, columnsorting

I am *completely* new to pandas, and python in general. I have a dataset, containing 18 columns. In the 10th column, I have "temp_c" representing temperatures in celsius, and in the 17th column, I have "temp_f" representing temperatures in fahrenheit. How do I select the temp_f and reposition it so that it will now appear in front of temp_c?

I'm attempting this in Jupyter notebook, but to no avail. I simply don't have enough experience to better articulate this question/problem.

```
df.sort_values('temp_f' , 'temp_c')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display the columns in your chosen order using `df[['temp_f', 'temp_c']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get locations of `temp_c` and `temp_f` using [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and swap the columns

```
c = df.columns.get_loc('temp_c')
f = df.columns.get_loc('temp_f')
cols = df.columns.tolist()
temp = cols[c+1] if c < len(cols)-1 else None
if temp:
    cols[c+1] = cols[f]
    cols[f] = temp
df = df[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_columns = df.columns.tolist()
new_columns = [...] # reorder your columns however you want,
                    # based on current_columns.

df = df[new_columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

one easy way is you redefine your dataframe.
let's say your data frame is df
then you can print out the column names

```
print(df.columns)
```

next, you copy the string in the bracket in the result, and change the columns you want to swich, for example ['1',...'17','18',...] to ['1',...'18','17',...]
and redefine your dataframe:

```
df=df[['1',...'18','17',...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility using [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
idx_c = df.columns.get_loc('temp_c')
idx_f = df.columns.get_loc('temp_f')

df.insert(idx_c-(idx_f<idx_c), 'temp_f', df.pop('temp_f'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7 col_8 col_9 temp_f temp_c col_11  \
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

  col_12 col_13 col_14 col_15 col_16  
0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```